# How to quick format a USB Drive in code

Tags: delphi, usb

I know which drive to format by using this code :

```
function IsRemovableDrive(Drive: Char): Boolean;
begin
Result := (Winapi.Windows.GetDriveType(PChar(Drive + ':\')) = Winapi.Windows.Drive_Removable);
end;
```

I tried this code :

```
const
SHFMT_DRV_A = 0;
SHFMT_DRV_B = 1;
SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT = $FFFF;
SHFMT_OPT_QUICKFORMAT = 0;
SHFMT_OPT_FULLFORMAT = 1;
SHFMT_OPT_SYSONLY = 2;
SHFMT_ERROR = -1;
SHFMT_CANCEL = -2;
SHFMT_NOFORMAT = -3;

function SHFormatDrive(hWnd: HWND; Drive: Word; fmtID: Word; Options: Word): Longint stdcall; external 'Shell32.dll' Name 'SHFormatDrive';


procedure TForm2.btnFormatClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FmtRes: Longint;
  cCharTemp : Char;
begin
  try
    cCharTemp := edtDrive.Text[1]; // edtDrive.Tex := 'E';
    FmtRes := ShFormatDrive(Handle, Ord(cCharTemp), SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT, SHFMT_OPT_QUICKFORMAT);
    case FmtRes of
      SHFMT_ERROR: ShowMessage('Error formatting the drive');
      SHFMT_CANCEL: ShowMessage('User canceled formatting the drive');
      SHFMT_NOFORMAT: ShowMessage('No Format')
        else
          ShowMessage('Disk has been formatted!');
    end;
  except
    ShowMessage('Error Occured!');
  end;
end;
```

When I try to run the code it it always say "Error formatting the drive"
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What has Google told you so far?

Comment: I tried this link but error :
http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=226

Comment: You need to be much more specific, and directly in your question, not later in the comments. How does it fail? Where do you get the error? What happens as opposed to what should happen? If you get an error message, what's the error message text?

Comment: I'll edit my question

Comment: Are you running it with elevated privileges? (Try running "As Administrator" and see if it works)

Comment: I tried running as administrator but still showing the same error('Error formatting the drive').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The final three parameters are `UINT`, a 32 bit type.  Declare them so rather than 16 bit `Word`.

The drive parameter is documented like this:

> The drive to format. The value of this parameter represents a letter drive starting at 0 for the A: drive. For example, a value of 2 stands for the C: drive.

You are passing the ASCII ordinal value for the letter. You need to convert `'E'` into `4`. Perhaps like this: `ord(driveChar) - ord('A')`.

As I read the docs, pass `$0001` as `options` for a quick format.

As always when working with Windows API, keep the documentation close: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762169.aspx

You'll be interested in this remark to be found there:

> The format is controlled by the dialog box interface. That is, the user must click the OK button to actually begin the format—the format cannot be started programmatically.

Your exception handler is needless since none of the function inside the `try/except` block are expected to raise exceptions.

Comment: I tried "ord(driveChar) - ord('A')" but still I get  the error. I also tried passing $0001 but still error. I even passed "4" as the drive but still error. I've been googling for hours already but can't find an answer. Do any have suggestions? or other solution? I just want to quick format the drive with very limited user intervention.

Comment: Did you read all of my answer? Read the first paragraph again, and fix the declaration of the function. Did you read the final paragraph? There will be user intervention? Did you read the MSDN docs? If the answer to any of these questions if no, why am I spending my time writing this stuff?

Comment: I never knew that Word and UINT will make the difference. It's now working. Thanks. I'll post my working source code as an answer.

Comment: It is only now I leared how to accept an answer. Thanks for the info

Comment: Thanks for the accept, and for doing to on your old questions. It's nice to meet a user that is keen to learn! Not always the case astonishingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
const
  SHFMT_DRV_A = 0;
  SHFMT_DRV_B = 1;
  SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT = $FFFF;
  SHFMT_OPT_QUICKFORMAT = 0;
  SHFMT_OPT_FULLFORMAT = 1;
  SHFMT_OPT_SYSONLY = 2;
  SHFMT_ERROR = -1;
  SHFMT_CANCEL = -2;
  SHFMT_NOFORMAT = -3;

function SHFormatDrive(
  hWnd: HWND; 
  Drive: UINT; 
  fmtID: UINT; 
  Options: UINT
): DWORD; stdcall; external 'Shell32.dll';

procedure TForm2.btnFormatClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FmtRes: Longint;
  cCharTemp : Char;
  nDrive : UINT; // this makes all the difference, declare its like this
begin
  try
    cCharTemp := edtDrive.Text[1]; // edtDrive.Text := 'E';
    nDrive := Ord(cCharTEmp) - Ord('A');
    FmtRes := ShFormatDrive(Handle, nDrive, SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT, SHFMT_OPT_QUICKFORMAT);
    case FmtRes of
      SHFMT_ERROR: ShowMessage('Error formatting the drive');
      SHFMT_CANCEL: ShowMessage('User canceled formatting the drive');
      SHFMT_NOFORMAT: ShowMessage('No Format')
        else
          ShowMessage('Disk has been formatted!');
    end;
  except
    ShowMessage('Error Occured!');
  end;
end;
```

Thanks to David Heffernan.

Comment: This largely repeats what my answer says, but misses out one crucial part, namely the declaration of the function.