# Calling ShFormatDrive from Delphi - last parameter ignored?

Tags: delphi, parameters, drive

```
function FormatUSBDrive(const DriveLetter: Char; const QuickFormat: Boolean): String;
var
  FmtRes:    Longint;
  cCharTemp: Char;
  nDrive:    UINT;
  handle:    THandle;

begin
  try
    handle    := Application.Handle;
    cCharTemp := Upcase(DriveLetter);
    nDrive    := Ord(cCharTemp) - Ord('A');
    if QuickFormat then
      FmtRes := ShFormatDrive(Handle, nDrive, SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT, SHFMT_OPT_QUICKFORMAT)
    else
      FmtRes := ShFormatDrive(Handle, nDrive, SHFMT_ID_DEFAULT, SHFMT_OPT_FULLFORMAT);
    //
    case FmtRes of
      SHFMT_ERROR:    Result := 'Error: Formatting the drive failed.';
      SHFMT_CANCEL:   Result := 'User canceled formatting the drive.';
      SHFMT_NOFORMAT: Result := 'Error: Drive cannot be formatted.';
      else            Result := 'Disk has been formatted!';
    end;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Result := 'FormatUSBDrive - Error:' + #13 + E.Message;
  end;
end;
```

In both case the Windows Format dialog pops up with the Quick format checkbox checked. What might I be doing wrong?

NOTE: I am NOT asking how to format a USB drive - my code works fine for that! I want to know why in both case the 'Quick format' checkbox is checked!

Comment: Please edit the question and include declarations of constant parameters you are passing.   If you pass wrong number, API will not behave as expected.

Comment: Most likely also a wrong declaration of the function as in [How to quick format a USB Drive in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534851/) - your example not only misses crucial parts but also which values `nDrive` and `FmtRes` have.

Comment: Whoever closed this, needs to work on his/her reading/comprehension skills! NOT AT ALL the same/similar questions!

Comment: Linking to that question does not limit it to USB as media - it is meant to compare the code there with yours and learn from points/issues being talked about it there. Also you're lacking reading (or understanding) comments at least yourself: your code alone still doesn't show how the constants are defined and how you call that function. Why not including that when editing your Q?